# How to display size of Blob for vehicle clasification?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm now working around with a car counting program. Now I want to display the size or area of the blob on each car to find the similarities in size in each kind of vehicles for further on I will try classify them. However, I don't really know how to display the size of the Blob, I try using blobs[i].currentBoundingRect. and when I did that a list of [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqpD2.png) appear, can I use any of them? Can you guys give me some advice or recommendations regarding the Blob's size displaying and vehicle classification? Thank you in advance.

P/s: When I try blobs[i].currentBoundingRect.area, there is error: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member. After adding parenthesis after area, another error occurs: error C2248: 'cv::String::String': cannot access private member declared in class 'cv::String'

```
void drawBlobInfoOnImage(std::vector<Blob> &blobs, cv::Mat &imgFrame2Copy) {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < blobs.size(); i++) {

         if (blobs[i].blnStillBeingTracked == true) {
            cv::rectangle(imgFrame2Copy, blobs[i].currentBoundingRect, SCALAR_RED, 2);

            int intFontFace = CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
            double dblFontScale = blobs[i].dblCurrentDiagonalSize / 60.0;
            int intFontThickness = (int)std::round(dblFontScale * 1.0);

            cv::putText(imgFrame2Copy, blobs[i].currentBoundingRect.height, blobs[i].centerPositions.back(), intFontFace, dblFontScale, SCALAR_GREEN, intFontThickness);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of "size" do you want? You could use the radius of minEnclosingCircle or width and height of minAreaRect and many others...

Answer (score 0):

`cv::Rect::area` is a method of the `Rect` class and not an attribute.
Which means you have to call the method by using parenthesis like this: `blobs[i].currentBoundingRect.area()`.